# Serial processing in spring integration

Tags: spring-integration

Is it possible to have serial processing in spring integration that is the response of one request is get to the next as its request. I have a requirement where only after getting response from service-1 I can initiate call to service-2. This was suggested so because only service-1 has a roll back service implemented. 
 Is it possible to control which request is processed first, I want request 1 to be processed first. Is this also possible

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking - the default behavior of wiring any reply producing endpoint to the next endpoint with a direct channel means the result of the first is the request to the second. If this is not what you are asking, please reword your question with more clarity and much more information.

Comment: I have a requirement where I have to hit two different web services but with the condition that if and only if response of the first is successful will we make the second webservice call. So I wanted to know how this could be handled

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It really depends on what you are trying to do, but the general solution would be to use a `<publish-subscribe-channel/>` set the `order` on the first service to "1" and the second to "2".

By default, the second service will only be called if the first is successful.

If you need to aggregate the results, add an aggregator downstream of both services.